# Can´t add values to an array after array_shift

Tags: php

I add values to an associative array with this code:

```
$tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
```

This works fine. But after I sort the array and shift it with that code:

```
$sortedarray = krsort($tokenarray, 1);
$shiftedarray = array_shift($sortedarray);
$shiftedarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
$tokenarrayjson = json_encode($shiftedarray);
```

This error appears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in SITE Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in SITE on line

$shiftedarray += [$datetime => $newtoken]; <- This line throes the error
```

Can someone tell my why please? Does array_shift make an object out of my array and if so, how can I prevent it?

Regards, Andreas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) does not return the sorted array, it sorts its argument in-place and returns true/false dependent on whether it succeeds or not. The same applies to [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), which returns the value shifted off the array, not the array post shift: You need to do this instead:

```
$sortedarray = $tokenarray;
krsort($sortedarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
$shiftedarray = $sortedarray;
array_shift($shiftedarray);
$shiftedarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
$tokenarrayjson = json_encode($shiftedarray);
```

If you don't actually need the intermediate arrays, you can simplify that to:

```
krsort($tokenarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
array_shift($tokenarray);
$tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
$tokenarrayjson = json_encode($tokenarray);
```

**Note**

Since your keys are numeric strings, `array_shift` will interpret them as numbers and renumber your array starting from 0. To avoid this, use `unset` on the first key of the array (found using [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)) instead:

```
krsort($tokenarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
unset($tokenarray[key($tokenarray)]);
$tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
$tokenarrayjson = json_encode($tokenarray);
```

Also note that you should use `SORT_NUMERIC` instead of 1, just in case the value changes in a future version of PHP.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GCSpU)

Comment: Nick, im sorry for bothering you, but can you tell me if there is a way to echo a variable of php in the browsers console? I work with javascript ajaxs so when I test it I don´t see whats going on in the php-file.

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer When I want to do that I usually include an extra field in the JSON I return from my ajax call (e.g. `'status' => 'here is a message'`) and then in my JS I use something like `if ('status' in result) alert(result.status);`